# Mongo / mongoose Sort error operation used more then maximum bytes of ram. I can't get index to work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a mongo db set up with mongoose. I'm trying to use sort to display them on a dashboard in 10's but around inspection 140 I'm getting MongoError: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM.

I'm trying to add an index to keep the performance up, but something seems to be not working.

here's the schema.

```
const InspectionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    inspectionId: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    inspector: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'users',
      required: true,
    },
    inspectorName: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
    },
    status: {
      type: Schema.Types.String,
      enum: statuses,
      default: STATUS.IN_PROGRESS.value,
      required: true,
    },
    archived: {
      type: Schema.Types.Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    data: {
      type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
      required: true,
    },
    report: {
      type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

and then this is my sort call:

```
      .limit(parseInt(query.limit))
      .skip(query.limit * query.page)
      .sort({
        createdAt: 'desc',
      })
      .then((inspections) => {
        return res.json({
          success: true,
          count,
          inspections: inspections.map((inspection) => ({
            ...inspection.toObject(),
            inspector: inspection.report.inspector,
          })),
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          success: false,
        });
      });
```

the query.limit is usually 10, the query page is the page number on dashboard displaying them.

and it usually hits memory limit around 140 inspections. mongoose add's in the createdAt and an _id. thinking _id would be an index I have tried:

```
BoundInspection.find(filter)
      .limit(parseInt(query.limit))
      .skip(query.limit * query.page)
      .sort({
        _id: -1,
        createdAt: 'desc',
      })
      .then((inspections) => {
        return res.json({
          success: true,
          count,
          inspections: inspections.map((inspection) => ({
            ...inspection.toObject(),
            inspector: inspection.report.inspector,
          })),
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          success: false,
        });
      });
```

but it still hits same error at same spot.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you run combinations like index + field things change. IMHO you should create an index that you can use in the query. createdAt is NumberOfDocs/10 or /20 that could work. `_id` + `createdAt` could also potentially work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by sorting by just _id. that is mongoose's default index. and _id keeps the same order as created at. will keep an eye on it to make sure.

```
BoundInspection.find(filter)
      .limit(parseInt(query.limit))
      .skip(query.limit * query.page)
      .sort({
        _id: -1,
      })
      .then((inspections) => {
        return res.json({
          success: true,
          count,
          inspections: inspections.map((inspection) => ({
            ...inspection.toObject(),
            inspector: inspection.report.inspector,
          })),
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          success: false,
        });
      });
```

I found this easier then created a new index as suggested by Minsky.

Comment: that sounds good. not only that but you can get the creation date from _id - if it's generated by mongod. It's a really cool index.